# Discounted Optimal Stopping

Tags: dynamic-programming, optimal-strategy

The model is as followed:

Consider an infinite horizon discounted problem $(0 < γ < 1)$ in which the state space is finite, with $n$ states, and there are only two possible decisions: stop or continue.

If at time $t$ you are at state $s$, and you decide to stop, you incur a stopping cost $γ^t g(s)$, and
move to a cost-free state, at which you stay forever.

If at time $t$ you are at state $s$, and you decide to continue, you incur a continuation cost $γ^tc(s)$,
and move to a next state $s_0$, selected at random according to transition probabilities $p_{s,s'}$.

Assume that all $g(s)$ and $c(s)$ are nonnegative. The stationary policy $π$ is completely specified in terms of the set $S_π$ at which the policy decides to stop. Let $π_0, π_1, . . .$ be the sequence of policies generated by the policy iteration algorithm, starting with a given arbitrary policy $π_0$.

My question is: How to identify if  $S_{\pi_{2}}\subset S_{\pi_{1}}\subset S_{\pi_{0}}$?

Comment: For starters, if $\pi_0$ never stops, then you know this doesn't hold, and its not really hard to show that if $\pi_0$ always stops, then this does hold.

Comment: @nir shahar Hi, may I ask if is it possible to use the mathematical expressions to explain this?